# Is there a managed/.NET way to access the summary information for a file?

Tags: .net, file

When you right-click on a file in Windows and select "Properties" from the menu, it opens the Properties window. On that window for most files types there's a "Summary" tab that contains a variety of information.

Is there a managed/.NET way to retrieve that information? I had assumed incorrectly that this would be a trivial thing to do and that it would all be part of some dictionary object on the System.IO.FileInfo object and you could just feed it a string of the tag you wanted and it would return some value. I was way wrong.

In my searches all I've been finding are shell commands, mentions of api calls or installing com objects. Those are fallback solutions (and ones I would rather avoid). What I really want to know is if I'm overlooking a .NET way of accessing that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called [Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369(VS.85).aspx) and this information is accessible via [`StgOpenStorageEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380342(VS.85).aspx) which is in `Ole32.dll`. Looking at the [pinvoke.net page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/StgOpenStorageEx.html) for this method, it appears that some of the functionality can be extracted using [`System.IO.Packaging.StorageInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.storageinfo_members.aspx) but that it requires some work to do this and it looks like you still have to use P/Invoke.

Comment: Yeah, you're confirming what I had discovered. sigh, I was really hoping there was another way. Thanks for the answer even if it's one I was hoping not to hear!

Answer (score 0):

> I had assumed incorrectly that this
>   would be a trivial thing to do and
>   that it would all be part of some
>   dictionary object on the
>   System.IO.FileInfo object and you
>   could just feed it a string of the tag
>   you wanted and it would return some
>   value

```
System.IO.FileInfo.Attributes
```

Comment: That is not what he is looking for.

Comment: Oh, THAT. I think that's the OSs ability to read into known filetypes -- I don't think those are part of the filesystem (though they may be cached somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo?

```
var fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("c:\temp.txt");
```

Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [DSOfile.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q224351/) that lets you edit these for Office documents. Unfortunately, I don't think these properties are universal for files - they won't always be available.

Just re-read your paragraph saying that COM objects are fallback solutions - however, this is the solution provided on the MS website, so I don't think you're going to do much better.